# detecting hough lines on binary images

Tags: opencv

I am using cv2.houghlines with these parameters to detect lines. With the first image which is color I have no problem detecting lines but the second one which is gray scale it detects no lines. I played with the parameters but no joy.

```
 rho = 1 # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
 theta = np.pi/180 # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
 threshold = 28 #28 #200
 min_line_length = 40 #80 #220 #minimum number of pixels making up a line
 max_line_gap = 5


 lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), minLineLength=min_line_len, maxLineGap=max_line_gap)
```

This is how I call it

```
if len(image.shape) >= 3:
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
else:
    gray = image
```

and these are the two images:
[image]

Comment: `cv2.HoughLinesP(gray, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, I multiplied the color image by 255 but not the gray combined image. I did it with the color one because it could not be displayed otherwise and since the gary one was displayed I did not think of do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us the complete code, because we don't know how do you know that there is no lines found. Did you print the size of variable lines? In c++ it would be:

```
cout << lines.size() << endl;
```

Or do you trying to draw the lines directly to the gray image with color value Scalar(255,0,0)?

Comment: Thanks, I found the error of my way. I listed it below. Not that I fully understand it though.